# Add column to Pandas dataframe, merging repeated rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the some data that looks like this:

```
City         1994 1995  1996  1997                           
Rome            X  NaN   NaN   NaN
New York      NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
Paris         NaN    X   NaN   NaN
Sidney        NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
```

The crosses represent that an event happened in that city in that specific year.
I want to add new years to my data frame, where the data looks like this:

```
City         1998                           
Rome            X
Sidney          X
London          X
Madrid          X
```

Basically the new data indicates where events happened in a new different year (so it'll always have 'X').
The result I'm looking for should look like this:

```
City         1994 1995  1996  1997   1998                          
Rome            X  NaN   NaN   NaN      X
New York      NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
Paris         NaN    X   NaN   NaN    NaN
Sidney        NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN      X
London        NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN      X
Madrid        NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN      X
```

So it should add the new non existing cities to the city list and put NaN for the already present years for that city and also put an X in the newly added year for the cities where the event occurred.

I tried using `df.append()` but I get repeaded values

```
City         1994 1995  1996  1997   1998                           
Rome            X  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
New York      NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
Paris         NaN    X   NaN   NaN    NaN
Sidney        NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
Rome          NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN      X
Sidney        NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN      X
London        NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN      X
Madrid        NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN      X
```

I also tried using `df.merge()` but I didn't get any better results. Any suggestions on how to do it using pandas? I can write some code to manually does it but it defeats the purpose of using such a powerful tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`df.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to achieve this.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [['Rome','X',  None,   None,   None],['New York' ,None,  None,   None,   None], ['Paris',None,  'X',   None,   None]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['City','1994', '1995',  '1996' , '1997' ])

df.head()

       City  1994  1995  1996  1997
0      Rome     X  None  None  None
1  New York  None  None  None  None
2     Paris  None     X  None  None

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['Rome', 'X', ],['Sydney','X'], ['London','X']], columns = ['City',         '1998'])

     City 1998
0    Rome    X
1  Sydney    X
2  London    X
```

Then you can merge the two DataFrame

```
df.merge(df2, how='outer')

       City  1994  1995  1996  1997 1998
0      Rome     X  None  None  None    X
1  New York  None  None  None  None  NaN
2     Paris  None     X  None  None  NaN
3    Sydney   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    X
4    London   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    X
```

You need to specify outer as type of merge to be performed.

> outer: use union of keys from both frames, similar to a SQL full outer
> join; sort keys lexicographically.

Comment: @MR I have updated the answer, can you check? If that is giving you desired output, you can mark is as accepted answer.

Comment: That does the trick, thank you very much!

Comment: This is a good answer. Just to add a little bit more context to it. merge is a versatile option to work with pandas, so if both dataframes have the same index/structure you could merge both dataframes based on the same reference index/column (like a left join). This is also an important remark. (external [reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-the-difference-between-join-and-merge-in-pandas/) ) @lrfanuddin